# How to make \reversepath useful for drawing the following closed curve?

Tags: pstricks

I want to draw a batman logo. As it is symmetric about the vertical line, it should be more convenient to just define the right part (or the left part) first and then reflect it to get the other part. The important note you must consider is that the logo must be constructed by a closed curve that can be used as a clipping path.

According to `pst-news13` on page 4, we have `\reversepath` that can be used to construct a curve in reversed coordinates.

Unfortunately, I failed to use `\reversepath` as shown in the following code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=6pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

\pstVerb
{
    /theta 72 def
    /Major 6.0 def
    /Minor 3.3 def
    % b a t p2c ---> x y
    % where b (semi-minor), a (semi-major), t (theta)
    /p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def
}


\def\RightPart
{
    \psline(0,2.7)(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
    \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
    \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!Minor Major theta p2c)
    \psellipticarcn(0,0)(!Major Minor){(!Minor Major theta p2c)}{(!Minor Major theta neg p2c)}
    \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
    \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
}

\def\LeftPart
{
    \scale{-1 1}
    \reversepath
    \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
    \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
    \psellipticarcn(0,0)(!Major Minor){(!Minor Major theta p2c)}{(!Minor Major theta neg p2c)}
    \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!Minor Major theta p2c)
    \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
    \psline(0,2.7)(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
    \closepath
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7.85,-4.85)(7.85,4.85)
    \pscustom[dimen=middle]{\RightPart}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7.85,-4.85)(7.85,4.85)
    \pscustom[dimen=middle]{\LeftPart}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7.85,-4.85)(7.85,4.85)
    \pscustom[dimen=middle,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{\RightPart\LeftPart}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is how to use `\reversepath` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having wasted much time for figuring out how `\reversepath` works, its behavior is now understood.

`\reversepath` affects the previous paths rather than the following paths (that most people probably assume). Its behavior is inconsistent with other macros (such as `\scale`, `\translate`, etc) defined for `pscustom`. It is one of many other inconsistency in PSTricks. But it is still fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}


% b a t p2c ---> x y
% where b (semi-minor), a (semi-major), t (theta)
\pstVerb{/p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def}


\def\RightPart
{
    \psline(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
    \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
    \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!3.3 6.0 72 p2c)
    \psellipticarcn(6.0,3.3){(!3.3 6.0 72 p2c)}{(!3.3 6.0 72 neg p2c)}
    \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
    \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-7,-4)(7,4)
\pscustom[dimen=middle,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange,linewidth=6pt]
{
    \RightPart
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \RightPart
    \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And now Stiff Jokes will obtain a bounty from Stiff Jokes. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: It is impossible for the current implementation of the StackExchange system. Stiff Jokes can only obtain a bounty from Steve Jobs or vice verse.

Comment: No, this is not an inconsistency in PSTricks, but behaves like defined in the Postscript Language, see the redbook.